# Concrete category

Tags: ct.category-theory

A concrete category is a category C together with a function that assigns to each object A of C a set called the underlying set of A.
Example: The category of groups, equipped with the function that assigns to each group its underlying set in the usual sense, is a concrete category.
What is the underlying set for an object in a category of groups ?

Comment: As far as I can tell you answered your own question just before you asked it.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/ - mathoverflow is intended for “research level” questions, whereas this is more like an exercise for a first course in category theory.

Comment: You don't want a function, but a _functor_, and it has to be faithful.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying set for an object in the category of groups is just the underlying set of the group, there is no other name for it.